# How to register new car with SENTRI?

Tags: global-entry, trusted-traveler, sentri

What part of my SENTRI account after logging in do I go to on the web site to register my new car and remove my sold car?

Answer (score 3):

Login to your [Trusted Traveler account](https://ttp.cbp.dhs.gov/)

## Adding a Vehicle:

From the TTP Dashboard you can scroll down slightly, and under Program Memberships you should see Add Vehicle

[image]

## Removing a Vehicle

From the TTP Dashboard, on the right-hand-side you will see "Manage Vehicles"

[image]

In the Manage Vehicles dialog you will have the option to "Delete Vehicle"

[image]

I didn't click on the Delete Vehicle, but I suspect it'll ask you to confirm, and you should be all set.  My understanding is that it can take some time (anywhere from a few hours to several weeks, or even months) before the vehicle actually comes active on your account.  Until the new vehicle is active/approved, you *CANNOT* use it through SENTRI.  Doing so can put your SENTRI membership at risk!